# Best hierarchical php syntax for assigning a variable to values if they are set

Tags: php, variables

I want to do this for 5 sets of parameters is this the best way to do it or is there some simpler syntax?

```
if(isset($_GET['credentials'])) $credentials = $_GET['credentials'];
if(isset($_POST['credentials'])) $credentials = $_POST['credentials'];
if(isset($_POST['c'])) $credentials = $_POST['c'];
if(isset($_GET['c'])) $credentials = $_GET['c'];
```

Also with this same hierarchy.

Comment: Which PHP version are you willing to use?

Comment: phphphphphphpphp 7.1 sorry for the character count ;)

Comment: array of the keys, and loop?

Comment: never extract post\get

Comment: Didn't even know you could do that lol. PHP is weird!

Comment: @maxisme Extracting POST and GET probably isn't so good of an idea as you will pollute the global namespace.

Comment: @rtfm I've heard about don't use with $_GET and $_FILE, is it also insecure with $_POST?

Comment: @Smartpal yes, anyone can hit any url  with a post request as easy as a get one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP 7 introduced the *The null coalescing operator (??)*, which you can use like this:

```
$result = $var ?? 'default';
```

This will assign `default` to `result` if:

- `$var` is undefined.
- `$var` is `NULL`

You can also use multiple `??` operators:

```
$result = $null_var ?? $undefined_var ?? 'hello' ?? 'world'; // Result: hello
```

To answer your question, you should be doing something like:

```
$credentials = $_GET['c'] ?? $_POST['c'] ?? $_POST['credentials'] ?? $_GET['credentials'];
```

More details [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) and [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce)

Comment: so `$credentials =  $_GET['credentials'] ?? $_POST['credentials'] ?? $_POST['c'] ?? $_GET['c']` ?

Comment: @maxisme exactly, that will do the same thing you want in one line, but be aware that this only works in PHP 7 or newer.

Comment: @maxisme I just realized I'm wrong, you need to use the opposite order if you want to check `$_GET['c']` first then `$_POST['c']` then....

Comment: Thanks I did that! haha.

Comment: @maxisme Good, I updated the answer anyway for future readers.

Comment: I also wacked it out in a job interview. Went down a treat so thanks for that ;)