# Faster way to select either SESSION or COOKIE value if exists?

Tags: php

Do I have to write

```
if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    $name = $_SESSION['name'];
} elseif (isset($_COOKIE['name']) {
    $name = $_COOKIE['name'];
}
```

Everytime I make a feature of `Remember Me` for users who want to save their Log status? Is there a ready function to handle this Or do I make my function?

Comment: Depends on your PHP version, check my answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/48936792/2595450

Comment: @Mehdi that ver helpful.