# isset ternary convenient method in php

Tags: php

Is there a shortcut for:

```
$resource = isset($parts[1]) ? $parts[1] : "";
```

For associative arrays I know this works:

```
$resource = $person["name"] ?: "";
```

So is there something similar?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48936729/best-hierarchical-php-syntax-for-assigning-a-variable-to-values-if-they-are-set/48936792#48936792

Comment: yes! exactly...